# Using new FormData() for sending HttpRequest in Dart

Tags: forms, dart, httprequest

Could somebody explain how can `new FormData()` be used in Dart to send the data of a form to a server with `HttpRequest`? Any alternative way of getting and formatting the data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a basic example :

```dart
final xhr = new HttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', url);
xhr.onReadyStateChange.listen((e) {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
    // on OK
  }
});

// send datas by specifying each element
xhr.send(new FormData()
  ..append('field1', x1)
  ..append('field2', x2)
);

// send datas by using an existing form and adding some additional datas
xhr.send(new FormData(formElement)
  ..append('field1', x1)
);
```

Comment: Unless you have specific need for a full HttpRequest object, also consider using HttpRequest.request, (https://api.dartlang.org/dart_html/HttpRequest.request) as it returns a future to the response. Also see my write up on POSTing data from Dart: http://blog.butlermatt.me/?p=109

Comment: Great blog post Matthew.